# How to remove XFS filesystem warning in mongodb shell?

Tags: mongodb

Every time I start a mongodb shell, I get this annoying warning:

```
Server has startup warnings:
2020-02-01T08:54:27.220+0100 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten]
2020-02-01T08:54:27.220+0100 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2020-02-01T08:54:27.220+0100 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
```

I understand that in some environments, this is useful. But in my particular case, I'm using mongodb on a VPS server that has pre-installed ext4 filesystem. There is no option to change that. And it is not needed anyway - in this particular application, there are no performance problems and there will never be. The server is already overpowered for this application.

I was going through the documentation to find a command line option for suppressing this warning message, but there is none. Or maybe there is, but I couldn't find it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To permanently suppress this server warning you currently need to use the XFS filesystem. The warning was added due to [observed stalls with EXT4 during WiredTiger checkpoints](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-18314).

You may want to upvote & watch [SERVER-19790: Provide mechanism to clear/acknowledge startup warnings](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19790) in the MongoDB issue tracker.

If you want to suppress displaying this warning (and **all** other startup warnings), start your `mongo` shell session with [`--quiet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption-mongo-quiet).

The quiet option is typically only used for non-interactive scripts as otherwise you may miss an important warning. Startup warnings only appear once per `mongo` shell session and highlight potentially serious issues like having access control disabled (or in your case, a filesystem which can result in stalls during checkpoints).